# How can i manipulate checkbox selection?

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:linq_pay_app/src/CarBikeInsurance/widgets/LSLayout.dart';
import 'package:linq_pay_app/src/CarBikeInsurance/widgets/fields/LSTextField.dart';
import 'package:grouped_buttons/grouped_buttons.dart';

class HealthInsurance extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HealthInsuranceState createState() => _HealthInsuranceState();
}

class _HealthInsuranceState extends State<HealthInsurance> {

  List<String> selectedMembers;

  Widget Page1(){
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Residence Pincode",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            LSTextField(label: "Enter Pincode",),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget Page2(){
    return ListView(
        children: <Widget>[

          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, top: 14.0),
            child: Text("Add the members you want to insure:",
              style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20.0
              ),
            ),
          ),

        CheckboxGroup(
          labels: <String>[
          "Self",
          "Spouse",
          "Son",
          "Daughter",
          "Mother",
          "Father",
          "Mother-in-law",
          "Father-in-law",
          ],

        onChange: (bool isChecked, String label, int index) => print("isChecked: $isChecked   label: $label  index: $index"),
        onSelected: (List<String> checked) => selectedMembers=checked,
        ),
      ]
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: Text("Back"),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: Page2()
    );
  }
}
```

There are 2 issues:
1. If the user selects Son or daughter, he should get an option ahead of son field to add or subtract the number of son or daughter and can keep a track of how many son or daughter he has selected.

2. If the user selects his parents, he cannot select his mother-in-law and father-in-law and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it should help your issues:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HealthInsurance()));

class HealthInsurance extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HealthInsuranceState createState() => _HealthInsuranceState();
}

class _HealthInsuranceState extends State<HealthInsurance> {
  String _isRelationshipSelected = "";
  int _counterSon = 0;
  int _counterDaughter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _counterSon = 0;
      _counterDaughter = 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: _buildRadioButton());
  }

  Widget _buildRadioButton() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Relationships: ",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 13.0),
          ),
          _buildSizedBox(10.0),

          _buildIndividualRadioButton("Son"),
          _isRelationshipSelected == "Son" ? _buildSizedBox(5.0) : Container(),

          _isRelationshipSelected == "Son" ? _buildIncDcrButton() : Container(),
          _buildSizedBox(10.0),
          // Daughter
          _buildIndividualRadioButton("Daughter"),
          _isRelationshipSelected == "Daughter"
              ? _buildSizedBox(5.0)
              : Container(),

          _isRelationshipSelected == "Daughter"
              ? _buildIncDcrButton()
              : Container(),

          _buildSizedBox(10.0),
          // Mother
          _isRelationshipSelected == "Mother-in-law" ||
                  _isRelationshipSelected == "Father-in-law"
              ? Container()
              : _buildIndividualRadioButton("Mother"),
          _buildSizedBox(10.0),
          // Father
          _isRelationshipSelected == "Mother-in-law" ||
                  _isRelationshipSelected == "Father-in-law"
              ? Container()
              : _buildIndividualRadioButton("Father"),
          _buildSizedBox(10.0),
          // Mother-in-law
          _isRelationshipSelected == "Mother" ||
                  _isRelationshipSelected == "Father"
              ? Container()
              : _buildIndividualRadioButton("Mother-in-law"),
          _buildSizedBox(10.0),
          // Father-in-law
          _isRelationshipSelected == "Mother" ||
                  _isRelationshipSelected == "Father"
              ? Container()
              : _buildIndividualRadioButton("Father-in-law"),
          _buildSizedBox(10.0),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIndividualRadioButton(String value) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Radio(
          focusColor: Colors.blue,
          value: value,
          groupValue: _isRelationshipSelected,
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() {
              _isRelationshipSelected = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        Text(
          value,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 13.0),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSizedBox(double height) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: height,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIncDcrButton() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_isRelationshipSelected == "Son") {
                setState(() {
                  _counterSon = _counterSon + 1;
                });
              } else if (_isRelationshipSelected == "Daughter") {
                setState(() {
                  _counterDaughter = _counterDaughter + 1;
                });
              }
            }),
        SizedBox(width: 5.0),
        Text(
          _isRelationshipSelected == "Son"
              ? "$_counterSon"
              : _isRelationshipSelected == "Daughter"
                  ? "$_counterDaughter"
                  : "",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 5.0),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_isRelationshipSelected == "Son") {
                setState(() {
                  _counterSon =
                      _counterSon == 0 ? _counterSon : _counterSon - 1;
                });
              } else if (_isRelationshipSelected == "Daughter") {
                setState(() {
                  _counterDaughter = _counterDaughter == 0
                      ? _counterDaughter
                      : _counterDaughter - 1;
                });
              }
            }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```